# Is possible to pass a array as a model to a component in VueJs 3?

Tags: vuejs3

Well, I am new on VueJs 3 and I am trying to create a component which is a list of users. I want to pass an array of users to this component and watch a list with them slide in on my screen. After it, I want to press a button inside of the component and watch it slide out of my screen.

I don't know if it is ridiculously hard or easy... Someone can give a sketch of it?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use `transition-group` for that, it's fairly straight forward

Demo: (modified from [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-list.html#reusable-transitions))

```js
const Demo = {
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["John", "Judy"],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.items.unshift(["Albert", "Betty", "Hugo"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)])
    },
    addEnd() {
      this.items.push(["Andrew", "Guadeloupe", "Pepijn"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)])
    },
    remove() {
      this.items.pop()
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(Demo).mount('#list-demo')
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.list-enter-from,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="list-demo">
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
  <button @click="remove">Remove</button>
  <button @click="addEnd">Add</button>
  <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
    <span v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="list-item">{{ item }}</span>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```